# how do i get response after execute oracel sql ddl statemenet using java spring boot jdbc template?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring boot application. And i want to get response after execute all ddl statement. Like when i create table then response `Table created`, when create view then response `View Created` and similar to function,procedure,trigger and others all ddl statements.

In my code, when exception occurred then response like `drop function BMS.factorial11` to `ORA-04043: object FACTORIAL11 does not exist` and `drop table test_table` to `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

I want to get all response like when exception occurred. So my question is, is it possible in spring boot application?

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=url
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Controller.java

```
@PostMapping("/run-script")
    public String runScript(@RequestBody String sc) {
        try {
            db.execute(sc);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return n;
        }
```

Comment: Wrap your DDL script in a stored procedure or smth and log the output in a temp table or smth and define that as a return value of the sproc. Then you can have it back as a result set and parse it with RowMapper or smth. All in All - this is a bad approach. You should have the DDL outside of the application and run it with the dedicated tools from Oracle.

Comment: SQL injection: it's free real estate :)